# Multiply the values of columns by a value, which is found in a different dataset

Tags: r

In R, to create a set of new columns, I need to multiply the values of some columns by a value, which is found in a different dataset. My data looks like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame(
  id  = seq(1:5),
  d01 = c(1.5, 4, 3, 2, 1),
  d02 = c(1, 2, 1, 4.5, 3),
  d03 = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 5)
)

data2 <- data.frame(
  id = c('d01', 'd02', 'd03'),
  w  = c(2, 4, 1.5)
)
```

I want to multiply the values in `data1$d01` by 2 because in the row in `data2` where `id == d01`, `w == 2`. So my result should look like this:

```
result <- data.frame(
  id  = seq(1:5),
  d01 = c(1.5, 4, 3, 2, 1),
  wd01 = c(3, 8, 6, 4, 2),
  d02 = c(1, 2, 1, 4.5, 3),
  wd02 = c(4, 8, 4, 18, 12),
  d03 = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 5),
  wd03 = c(3, 6, 4.5, 3, 7.5)
)
```

In my real data, `data1` has 300.000 rows and this is happening inside a function which I am calling 10.000 times every time creating a different `data2` and `data1`. Therefore, computational speed is key, and the loop which I can write myself to solve this problem is too slow. The number of rows in `data2` (number of columns in data1 + id and the other variables in my real data) varies between each call to the function but is always between 2 and 35, while the number of columns in `data2` is always 4 (remaing columns not showed here for simplicity). The columns `data1` which I need to multiply always starts with `d0` and are the only columns with this naming pattern (same for the values of cells in `data2`).

Inside the function I also need to multiply the columns in data1 with values from a different column in data2, so I would prefer to add columns to data1 with the multiplied values, instead of modifying the original columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple for loop approach. I would be surprised if there are much faster solutions without reshaping your data to try to turn this into, say, matrix multiplication, but the reshaping would probably be more expensive than the efficiency gain for this single operation.

One way to speed things up might be to use `data.table`s instead of base data frames. Or perhaps just use matrices--you show no non-numeric data in your example; if a `matrix` would work for `data1` and `data2` were a vector in the right column order, that would probably be a good bit faster.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data2)) {
  data1[paste0("w", data2$id[i])] = data1[[data2$id[i]]] * data2$w[i]
}

data1
#   id d01 d02 d03 wd01 wd02 wd03
# 1  1 1.5 1.0   2    3    4  3.0
# 2  2 4.0 2.0   4    8    8  6.0
# 3  3 3.0 1.0   3    6    4  4.5
# 4  4 2.0 4.5   2    4   18  3.0
# 5  5 1.0 3.0   5    2   12  7.5
```

---

Turns out my instincts were wrong, and the for loop method is much faster than a matrix multiplication method, however the `lapply` method is even faster by a good bit. Here's a benchmark on "full size" data (results first, benchmarking code follows).

```
bench::mark(
  matrix_mult = matrix_mult(m1, w),
  for_loop = for_loop(data1, data2),
  lapply = lapply_replace(data1, data2),
  pivot = pivot(data1, data2),
  check = FALSE
)
  
#   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory               time            gc      
#   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>               <list>          <list>  
# 1 matrix_mult 226.35ms 264.33ms     3.78    323.9MB     3.78     2     2   528.65ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [90 × 3]>  <bench_tm [2]>  <tibble>
# 2 for_loop     47.28ms     52ms    17.4     120.3MB     1.93     9     1   516.81ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [440 × 3]> <bench_tm [9]>  <tibble>
# 3 lapply         8.4ms   9.34ms    84.9      81.3MB     5.93    43     3   506.21ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [244 × 3]> <bench_tm [43]> <tibble>
# 4 pivot          1.99s    1.99s     0.503     2.5GB     2.01     1     4      1.99s <NULL> <Rprofmem [737 × 3]> <bench_tm [1]>  <tibble>
# Warning message:
# Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
```

Code for benchmarking:

```
set.seed(47)
nr = 3e5
nc = 35
data1 = data.frame(id = 1:nr, replicate(nc, runif(nr)))
names(data1)[-1] = sprintf("d%02d", 1:nc)
data2 = data.frame(id = sprintf("d%02d", 1:nc), w = runif(nc))

m1 = as.matrix(data1)
w = data2$w

matrix_mult = function(m1, w) {
  res = m1[, -1] %*% diag(w)
  colnames(res) = paste0("w", colnames(m1)[-1])
  cbind(m1, res)
}

for_loop = function(d1, d2) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(d2)) {
      d1[paste0("w", d2$id[i])] = d1[[d2$id[i]]] * d2$w[i]
  }
  d1
}

lapply_replace = function(d1, d2) {
   d1[paste0("w",names(d1)[-1])] <- lapply(names(d1)[-1], \(x) {
      d1[,match(x, d2$id)+1] * d2[match(x, d2$id), "w"]
    })
   d1
}

pivot = function(d1, d2) {
  d1 %>%
      # Unpivot to 'id' | 'name' | 'value'.
      pivot_longer(!id) %>%
      # Match each 'w' to its appropriate column 'name'.
      left_join(d2,
        join_by(name == id)
      ) %>%
      mutate(
        # Multiply by 'w'...
        prod = value * w,
        # ...and also prefix the column 'name' with "w".
        name = paste0("w", name)
      ) %>%
      # Pivot to 'id' | 'wd01' | ... | 'wd03'. 
      pivot_wider(
        id_cols = id,
        values_from = prod,
        names_from = name
      ) %>%
      # Use 'id' to associate each 'wd*' with its 'd*'.
      right_join(d1, "id")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and benchmark it against the suggestions here. I

In the function call, before I reach this point, there are some steps where convert back and forth between matrices and data.frames to be able to do RowMins and left_join, respectively, and in the current place the data is in the data.frame format, because I just did a left_join before. When I profile my code I can see that the conversion is expensive, so I would prefer to not convert to matrix. 

But I suppose I could also do the left_join with a data.table. Would that also speed up your suggested for loop?

Comment: Yes, converting back and forth is expensive and should be avoided. If you'd like to improve your code overall, first you should profile it to see where the slowest parts are. Then, perhaps ask a new question, but adding unformatted code in comments isn't going to be a good way to work on the problem.

Comment: However, see my edits - I ran a benchmark and the matrix approach is actually quite a bit slower. Using `data.table`, even if you still use `dplyr` syntax with `dtplyr`, will likely speed things up.

Comment: @GregorThomas  I [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77996009/2) my solution to omit the final `join()`.  However, it reduces runtime only a little (10%), and ironically it consumes _more_ memory.

Answer (score 4):

`collapse::setop` is fast for this application. Timing using @GregorThomas' benchmark:

```
library(collapse) # for `setop`

collapse_setop <- function(d1, d2) {
  cbind(
    d1,
    setNames(setop(d1[,d2$id], "*", d2$w, rowwise = TRUE), paste0("w", d2$id))
  )
}
bench::mark(
  lapply = lapply_replace(data1, data2),
  collapse_setop = collapse_setop(data1, data2)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 lapply          17.86ms  19.11ms      49.7    81.3MB     137.
#> 2 collapse_setop   5.78ms   6.17ms     158.     28.7KB       0
```

NB: beware that `data1` is modified by reference when using `collapse_setop`, but if the operation is `data1 <- lapply_replace(data1, data2)`, it won't matter because all the data in `data1` is preserved in the output.

As a side note, for a rowwise minimum, using `do.call(pmin, data1[,-1])` will probably be faster than `as.data.frame(RowMins(as.matrix(data1[,-1)))`.

Comment: Why [`data.table::setnames()`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/setattr.html) instead of [```base::`names<-`()```](https://rdrr.io/r/base/names.html)?  Does it require modification by reference?

Comment: Sure. I went with `setNames`. It's just as fast and doesn't require any external packages.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in base R using `lapply` and `match`:

```
data1[paste0("w",names(data1)[-1])] <- lapply(names(data1)[-1], \(x) 
                                              data1[,match(x, data2$id)+1] * data2[match(x, data2$id), "w"]
```

Output:

```
  id d01 d02 d03 wd01 wd02 wd03
1  1 1.5 1.0   2    3    4  3.0
2  2 4.0 2.0   4    8    8  6.0
3  3 3.0 1.0   3    6    4  4.5
4  4 2.0 4.5   2    4   18  3.0
5  5 1.0 3.0   5    2   12  7.5
```

Answer (score 2):

A clear (but slower) solution in the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/).

```r
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate 'data1' and 'data2'.
# ...


data1 %>%
  # Unpivot to 'id' | 'name' | 'value'.
  pivot_longer(!id) %>%
  
  # Match each 'w' to its appropriate column 'name'.
  left_join(data2, join_by(name == id)) %>%
  
  # Multiply by 'w'.
  mutate(prod = value * w) %>%
  
  # Pivot to 'id' | 'd01' | ... | 'd02' | 'wd01' | ... | 'wd03'. 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = id,
    names_from = name,
    #             |---- Prefix products with "w" ----|
    names_glue = "{if_else(.value == 'prod', 'w', '')}{name}",
    values_from = c(value, prod)
  )
```

Comment: This is a nice tidy solution, however pivots are quite expensive and since OP is asking for a highly efficient solution, they are probably not a good choice here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
cbind(
  data1,
  `colnames<-`(
    t(t(data1[-1]) * with(data2, w[match(id, names(data1)[-1])])),
    paste0("w", names(data1)[-1])
  )
)
```